# UITableView top and bottom cells expanding on load and each update

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview, rubymotion

We are using an `UITableView` to layout some fields with labels, and we are getting some weird behavior.
We have a class called `TextFieldView` which implements `UITableViewCell`, and adds an `UITextField` and an `UILabel` to its `subviews`. The `TextFieldView` is then added as the cells of the table via the table-delegate. We use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The problem is, that when we initially load the table all cells have a height of 44. But when the table is loaded the first and the last cells frame is set to a height of 45. And again, each time we do a `table.beginUpdates/table.endUpdates` (on a text-update) the first and the last cells height is incremented by +1.

The reason we call begin/endUpdates is because we also have an `UITextView` which expands when we change its content. We have removed the `UITextView` though, to see if this had anything to do with the 'bug', and it does not.

We hope someone has had a similar problem - or can spot our brain-fart! - We are all out of ideas :-)

**Here is how we initialize our `UITableViewCell`:**

```
class TextFieldView < UITableViewCell
....
def init()
        super.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
        self.styleClass = 'control'
        @focus = UIImageView.alloc.initWithImage(UIImage.imageNamed('focus.png'))
        frame = self.frame

        @focus.frame = [[frame.size.width - 13, 8], [13, 28]]
        @focus.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
        @focus.hidden = true
        self.contentView.addSubview(@focus)

        size = self.frame.size  # 44 x 320
        self.styleClass = 'control text-field'

        @label = self.create_label([[10, 10], [140, 24]])
        self.contentView.addSubview(@label)

        @text_field = UITextField.alloc.initWithFrame([[160, 11], [size.width - 160 - 20, 24]])

        @text_field.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        @text_field.minimumFontSize = 13
        @text_field.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
        @text_field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone
        @text_field.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
        @text_field.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(17)
        @text_field.styleClass = 'control'
        self.contentView.addSubview(@text_field)

        #@text_field.delegate = is handle by the view controller

        self
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation for these symptoms that I can think of are not consistent with the code sample you have provided. If you dequeue re-usable cells and set them up assuming they are not being re-used you will be constructing cells that already have the required structure which may for example cause the cell size to increase by 1 pixel. If, for example, there is enough space to show 10 rows and you have 11, when you scroll up and down the first and last cells will be re-used and each time the changes will be applied. The code sample above shows a reuse identifier of nil indicating that you are not re-using cells. It is possible however that your table view data source attempts to dequeue cells (you haven't shown the code where you do that) even though the class you have shown assumes that this is not the case and somehow RubyMotion is calling the init after/whilst dequeueing the cell. Maybe that explanation will give you some ideas to investigate or help others with the same symptoms.

Comment: Thx for your answer. We ended up refactoring our code, and after that the glitch was gone. Im not sure this is the real cause, but it might help someone with a similar problem :-)